# Installing a package in R inside a script

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm a beginner with R. I want to launch R scripts at specific moments, managing this with Linux's `cron` and launching the scripts as `Rscript name_of_the_script`.

I have installed `tidyverse` in Rstudio, with `install.packages("tidyverse")`. Ok, but I guess that installation is specific to the Rstudio environment. When working in a script (not using Rstudio), and launching that script with Rscript, the library `tidyverse` is not installed. Even worse, I couldn't install it in the script with `install.packages("tidyverse")`.

What do you suggest? Thanks.

Comment: That is not the case. The packages are installed in 'R' environment not RStudio. You should specify the location of library on your machine using ```.libPaths()```. That should help.

Answer (score 2):

The library is, in fact, probably installed. It is difficult to be sure of what is the problem without more details, but I would guess that you did not load your library in your script. Try to add the following at the beginning on the first line of your script

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Comment: Yes, I have included that line. It works for Rstudio, but not in a general script written out of Rstudio in some specific directory.

Comment: Try `library(tidyverse, lib.loc="path/to/your/library")` to specify where the library has been installed

Comment: Thanks, but how do I know where the installation from Rstudio is made? With Rstudio opened, I just typed `install.packages("tidyverse")`.

Comment: As suggested by @makeshift-programmer, you can type `.libPaths()` in RStudio to see where the package have been installed by default.

Comment: You might have R version conflict. Rstudio might be using a specific version and Rscript might be using other. Try using entire path for Rscript. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26910560/7590064

Answer (score 2):

The solution is you simply use `require()` to load your package without worrying about the path.

```
require(dplyr)
```