# Loading R package inside R script

Tags: r, bash, tidyverse, r-package, rscript

I tried several ways on loading few specific packages inside my `script.R` to run the script in terminal by typing `./Rscript script.R`. There is no problem with the script but I get an error when I want to load a package e,g `tidyverse`.

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")):
number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 3.6.0
```

Based on this link [Installing a package in R inside a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58347125/installing-a-package-in-r-inside-a-script) I tried to find the location of the library by typing `.libPaths()` in Rstudio then I gave the path to load the package inside the `script.R` by typing
`library(tidyverse,lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library")`

Again I get the same error.
Could you please mention where is the mistake happening? Thanks

Comment: This might be of help - https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_load_packages_from_an_R_script_using_R_CMD_BATCH_via_the_command_prompt - among other options, they suggest making your own code a package so that it calls dependencies by itself.

Comment: Also, do you get that same problem with any other package, or is ```tidyverse``` the only one?

Comment: You might also see if ```require()``` has the same result. You can find a script that uses require and checks whether it was successful here - https://yihui.org/en/2014/07/library-vs-require:

```if (require('foo')) {
  awesome_foo_function()
} else {
  warning('You missed an awesome function')
}```

Comment: @PabloHerrerosCantis I tried with ```readr``` and I still get the same error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is loading the package by `require()`

```
require(dplyr)
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that [it is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28422554/11801854) to use `require()` to load packages. If using `library()` fails, there's no reason why `require()` would work.

From your question, it looks like you're using a certain `Rscript` binary in your current folder (`./Rscript`), this might not be using the same version of `R` as RStudio is doing.

You could try running

```
Rscript -e "library(tidyverse)"
```

to see if you can load `tidyverse`. Note that I'm using the `Rscript` command here instead of `./Rscript`. This should point to your latest R version installed and the same one RStudio is using.

If the error persists, you could just try re-installing `tidyverse` using

```
Rscript -e "install.packages('tidyverse')"
```