# How to start specific R installation on ubuntu

Tags: r

on my ubuntu server I have several R installation created by RStudio Server.
That is, there is a `/home/user1/R` and a `/home/user2/R`.
I now want to run an R command from command line. Usually I just type s.th. like `sudo R -e "...."`. However, how can I specify which R installation to be used with that approach?

Whenever I execute the command, the R installation that is used is `/usr/local/lib/R`. How can i change this?

Comment: Try changing the `$PATH` https://stackoverflow.com/a/26910560/10276092

Comment: You can use the full path rather than just `R`. Your shell will use whichever one it finds first on your PATH environment variable.

Comment: what is the full path?

Comment: The full path is the complete location of the R binary file you want to run, maybe `sudo /home/user2/R/bin/R -e 1+1`